# Left-align last gallery row

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, gallery

I have a picture gallery that looks like:
[image]

The code looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="squares">
        <a href="yourlinkhere1.php"><img src="images/galleryimage1.jpg"></a>
        <h5>IMG_114</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="squares">
        <a href="yourlinkhere2.php"><img src="images/galleryimage2.jpg"></a>
        <h5>IMG_115</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
}

#squares {
    background: #00ff00;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 300px;
}

#squares img {
    max-height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}

#squares h5 {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I like how it turned out, but I would like `IMG_117` to align under `IMG_114`, while keeping the green area centered and the content in the div centered...Not sure how to get that div aligned left without un-centering something else.

I was thinking this could be a quick tweak to my css or maybe some jQuery to add two more columns to the `IMG_117` row. The issue I see though is this is dynamic content and I won't always know how many are in the last row...could be one, two, or three and if there is some jQuery it would need to check and see how many items are in the row and then add the missing columns.

I'm not sure which approach is the easiest or if there is a better solution out there...does anyone have any ideas or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flexbox solution for more fluid and flexible layout see the solution at codepen below.

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ff0000;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 5% 0;
}
```

**Codepen**

```
https://codepen.io/ahmedi/pen/KvVgQW
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code and everything looks good! I didn't even think about the flex property!

Comment: Thanks! Josh Rodgers FlexBox is awesome property of css3 you can also use it in many layouts.

Answer (score 0):

at first replace all id="squares" with class="squares" in html
and #squares with .squares

**id** - meant to be unique identifier of the DOM element on the page

then add to your css:

```
.squares {
   float: left; /* all elements will tend to left*/
}
.wrapper {
  clear: both; /* reset rules of floating for the next elements*/
}
```

Comment: This was very close, unfortunately the entire list (green section) did not remain centered...but I appreciate the contribution :-)